# How to get node weights from networkx to dgl

Tags: python, networkx, dgl

Consider the following toy networkx graph:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
G.nodes[0]["weight"] = 0
G.nodes[1]["weight"] = 10
G.nodes[2]["weight"] = 20
G.nodes[3]["weight"] = 30
```

I would like to use that in [dgl](https://www.dgl.ai/) but I am not sure how to read in the node weights. I attempted:

```
import dgl
dgl.from_networkx(G, node_attrs="weight")
```

but that gives:

```
File ~/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dgl/convert.py:1279, in from_networkx(nx_graph, node_attrs, edge_attrs, edge_id_attr_name, idtype, device)
   1277 for nid in range(g.number_of_nodes()):
   1278     for attr in node_attrs:
-> 1279         attr_dict[attr].append(nx_graph.nodes[nid][attr])
   1280 for attr in node_attrs:
   1281     g.ndata[attr] = F.copy_to(_batcher(attr_dict[attr]), g.device)

KeyError: 'w'
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the dgl doc here](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.6.x/generated/dgl.from_networkx.html), it looks like `node_attrs` should be a list of attribute names. So if you change `dgl.from_networkx(G, node_attrs="weight")` to
`dgl.from_networkx(G, node_attrs=["weight"])`, you will get the result you want.

See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import dgl

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
G.nodes[0]["weight"] = 0
G.nodes[1]["weight"] = 10
G.nodes[2]["weight"] = 20
G.nodes[3]["weight"] = 30

dgl.from_networkx(G, node_attrs=["weight"])
```

And output:

```
Graph(num_nodes=4, num_edges=3,
      ndata_schemes={'weight': Scheme(shape=(), dtype=torch.int64)}
      edata_schemes={})
```

Comment: Thank you very much